# need first volley request response to make json object for second request

Tags: android, json, api, android-volley, multipart

I have a big problem with volley request sequence and making json array out of first request response for second request.

this is the code :

```
    JSONObject imageAddedResponse = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray imagesAddedResponse = new JSONArray();
```

---

```
public void postImageData(Context applicationContext, String title, String note, ArrayList<ContentData> mImages, String videoPath, final Listeners.APIPostDataListener listener) {

    //Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);

    Settings settings = new Settings(applicationContext);
    String selectedURL = settings.getChosenUrl();
    final String token = settings.getTokenKey();
    String url = "http://" + selectedURL + "/databox/api/v1/upload/files";
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    params.put("Content-Disposition", "form-data" + "; charset=utf-8");

    //POST data to CMS to get JSONObject back
    for (int i = 0; i < mImages.size(); i++) {
        String path = String.valueOf(mImages.get(i).getPath());
        File file = new File(path);
            MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(url, file, Response.class, params, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onAPIPostData(String.valueOf(response), true);
                    }
                    if (response != null || response != "") {
                        try {
                            imageAddedResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject jsonArraydata = imageAddedResponse.getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray jsonArrayImages = jsonArraydata.getJSONArray("images");
                            imagesAddedResponse.put(jsonArrayImages);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley Request Error", error.toString());
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onAPIPostData("", false);
                    }
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    //POST request to add entity to CMS
    JSONObject jsonimages = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArrayimages = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < imagesAddedResponse.length() ; i++){
        try {
            JSONObject getObjectValues = imagesAddedResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            jsonimages.put("id",getObjectValues.getString("id"));
            jsonimages.put("src",getObjectValues.getString("src"));
            jsonimages.put("size",getObjectValues.getString("size"));
            jsonimages.put("baseName",getObjectValues.getString("baseName"));
            jsonimages.put("type",getObjectValues.getString("type"));
            jsonimages.put("db_languages_id", "1");
            jsonimages.put("title",String.valueOf(mImages.get(i).getTitle()));              
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("title", title);
        json.put("description", note);
        json.put("db_languages_id", "1");
        json.put("db_user_id", "3");
        jsonArray.put(json);
        finalobject.put("data", jsonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String urlFinal = "http://" + selectedURL + "/databox/api/v1/1/entity";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(urlFinal, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // response
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onAPIPostData(String.valueOf(response), true);
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onAPIPostData("", false);
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };
    postRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
}
```

first request post to CMS and get some information for images posted and then I need to add those information to next post to make entity based on response I got back from first post request.

Comment: @Angad Tiwari this the question

Comment: yahh... gotit... :-)

Comment: @saeid let me clear with this. 1. you call MultiPartRequest (which i think is a custom class that extend Request<>) for each image upload to server. 2. after each succesful image upload to server you got response with imp data. 3. you need to call JsonObjectRequest after all successful image upload done. Is this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Angad Tiwari... you are right , this is the procedure , after 2nd you mentioned i get json response back , i need to make another jsonarray out of that response for next request

Comment: check your mail

Comment: @ Angad Tiwari ...replied

Comment: have u succeed?

Comment: @ Angad Tiwari ... not much , check your mail plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int totalSuccesfulImagePost = 0; //this variable increment when each succesful response from multipart-request

public void postImageData(Context applicationContext, String title, String note, ArrayList<ContentData> mImages, String videoPath, final Listeners.APIPostDataListener listener) {

      //Instantiate the RequestQueue.
      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);

      Settings settings = new Settings(applicationContext);
      String selectedURL = settings.getChosenUrl();
      final String token = settings.getTokenKey();
      String url = "http://" + selectedURL + "/databox/api/v1/upload/files";
      HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
      params.put("Content-Disposition", "form-data" + "; charset=utf-8");

      //POST data to CMS to get JSONObject back
      for (int i = 0; i < mImages.size(); i++) {
          String path = String.valueOf(mImages.get(i).getPath());
          File file = new File(path);
          MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(url, file, Response.class, params, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onAPIPostData(String.valueOf(response), true);
                }
                if (response != null || response != "") {
                    try {
                        imageAddedResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject jsonArraydata = imageAddedResponse.getJSONObject("data");
                        JSONArray jsonArrayImages = jsonArraydata.getJSONArray("images");
                        imagesAddedResponse.put(jsonArrayImages.getJSONObject(0));
                        totalSuccesfulImagePost++; //here we increase the count
                        postRequest(token); //call this method and check wheather all the image uploaded or not

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley Request Error", error.toString());
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onAPIPostData("", false);
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
   }
}

//make this as seperate method and call when all multipart-request call succesful
public void postRequest(String token){

    if(totalSuccesfulImagePost != mImages.size()) {
        //this means not all the images posted yet, hence return the method
        return;
    }

    //POST request to add entity to CMS
    JSONObject jsonimages = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArrayimages = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < imagesAddedResponse.length() ; i++){
        try {
        JSONObject getObjectValues = imagesAddedResponse.getJSONObject(i);
        jsonimages.put("id",getObjectValues.getString("id"));
        jsonimages.put("src",getObjectValues.getString("src"));
        jsonimages.put("size",getObjectValues.getString("size"));
            jsonimages.put("baseName",getObjectValues.getString("baseName"));
            jsonimages.put("type",getObjectValues.getString("type"));
            jsonimages.put("db_languages_id", "1");
            jsonimages.put("title",String.valueOf(mImages.get(i).getTitle()));              
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("title", title);
        json.put("description", note);
        json.put("db_languages_id", "1");
        json.put("db_user_id", "3");
        jsonArray.put(json);
        finalobject.put("data", jsonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();.getJSONObject(0)
    }
    String urlFinal = "http://" + selectedURL + "/databox/api/v1/1/entity";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(urlFinal, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // response
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onAPIPostData(String.valueOf(response), true);
            }
        }
    },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onAPIPostData("", false);
                }
            }
        }
) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return params;
    }
};
    postRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
}
```

updated your code. Hope this may help you.

1. I've created new method for JsonObjectRequest with the name postRequest();
2. totalSuccesfulImagePost variable holds the no. of succesfull response for image upload
3. new method postRequest() calls at each multipart-request response
4. postRequest() methods check if not all response process yet than skip the 2nd api call

> Also see how fb do this batch request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/ -> Batch Reqest

Note -

1. Ive increment the variable totalSuccesfulImagePost and handle in each response, although you need to Response.ErrorListener()
2. Although you can go with the ThreadPoolExecutor option where each thread is created to handle each multipart-request upload and after all thread execution , call the method postRequest()

Work-around using ThreadPoolExecutor

a) Create ThreadPoolExecutor & initialize min/max pool size

b) Asign each mulitpart-request to upload image to each thread

c) Add all thread (contain image upload multipart-request) to ThreadPoolExecutor

d) Execute pool

e) call postRequest() method when ThreadPoolExecutor is empty i.e. this means all the thread execution is done and ready to call postRequest()

Answer (score 0):

it is possible using Priority Of each Request.

```
    private Priority priority = Priority.HIGH;

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_STRING_REQ, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

    };

    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

Comment: thank you for answer @sathish gadde ... would you explain it a bit more , this did not help me so far